# How to store and access the data from excel sheet given as an input in html

Tags: html, excel

I need to create dynamic graphs using the data in excel which is given as an input to html page.

Comment: Have you just selected a random collection of tags? What does this have to do with Java or angular?

Comment: _I need to create_ Please go ahead and create :)

Comment: I am using angular js for displaying the data dynamically@Liam

Answer (score 1):

1) Upload the excel from html page by sending it into java back-end by calling api.

2) From java back-end, parse the data from excel and return as json response to above api.

3) Use some graph library to show the graph from the json response.

Hope it helped. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very generic question and would give you some heads up on how to proceed.
Use `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook`

```html
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(excelFile); // takes arg in BufferedInputStream format
  int numOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
  
  for(int i = 0; i < numOfSheets ; i++){
   
   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
   for(Row row : sheet){
     for(Cell cell : row){
    String value = null;
    if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
      String valueStr = cell.getStringCellValue();
    }else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
      int value = ((Double)cell.getNumericCellValue()).intValue();// you may need to change datatypes here
    }else if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN){
      boolean valueBool = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
    }
     }
   }
        }
```

you can use methods like `row.getRowNum()` if this returns 0, its header row generally, which would serve as your x axis and rest might be your values. You can use chart.js(easy) or any other suitable library for creating graphs.